# Python: Compare sys.argv with a string

Tags: python

This seems like it should be so simple, but i am having some serious issues. All i want to do is see if the user input matches a 2 letter expression. I guess my biggest problem i have is that i am not very familiar with the re library and the documentation does not really help me too much.

This is what i have tried so far:

try 1

```
if re.match(sys.argv[3],  "GL",  re.I):
    input_file_path = "V:\\test"
```

try 2

```
if re.ignorecase(sys.argv[3],  "GL"):
    input_file_path = "V:\\test"
```

try 3

```
if sys.argv[3] == "GL":
    input_file_path = "V:\\test"
```

The way i call the program to run: filename.py tester test GL
"tester" and "test" are not really used yet.

EDIT: I found my main problem. I was calling a bunch of if statements rather than elif. So the last one that said else: exit() always got hit (cause i was testing the first if). rookie mistake

Comment: Did you remember to account for sys.argv[0] being the name of the script?

Comment: 1) Is `domain` equal to `sys.argv[3]`? 2) If the string should match exactly "GL", don't bother using the `re` module, which is for much more general comparisons. Just use simple string comparison as in try 3.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, when i print sys.argv[3] it prints out GL. yes, domain is equal (i edited that part)

Comment: Are you sure you're not re-setting `input_file_path` some place else?

Comment: You're using `re.match()` wrong. The search pattern is the first argument, the string you want to search comes second. But that is not the only problem, it seems.

Comment: Might I suggest using an actual commandline parsing library?  `argparse` is in the standard library as of python2.7 and works with earlier versions than that.  There's `optparse` too if that suits your fancy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just convert the string to test to lowercase before comparing and you should be fine:

```
if sys.argv[3].lower() == "gl":
    input_file_path = "V:\\test"
```

More notably, regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

Comment: If this works, then I would have thought that `try 1` would have worked.  (although this is certainly better).

Comment: @mgilson: He has the order of parameters mixed up, the pattern comes first, the to-be-matched string second.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I knew about the anchoring with re.match (vs. re.search) (this answer anchors the comparison at the start [and end] of the string too).  I didn't think about the order of the parameters, but you're correct. Thanks.

Comment: @mgilson: Right, the first part of my comment wasn't relevant to the problem. Have deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Your re.match is backward. The pattern comes first. Try:

```
if re.match('GL', sys.argv[3], re.I):
    input_file_path = "V:\\test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the third argument is not 'GL'. `print sys.argv` and you will see that. My guess is that you are off by one in your index.

Show us the commandline you use to run your script.

---

> printing the sys.argv[3] prints exactly GL – LiverpoolFTW

---

Then the bug is elsewhere. If you print `sys.argv[3].lower() == "gl"` just before, and `input_file_path` just after, you will see the expected values. What you really need here is a debugger. `pdb` is the built-in standard, but I highly recommend `pudb`.

For quick setup, paste these into a terminal. `virtualenv` is a industry standard for keeping project dependencies separate.

```
cd ~
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/1.6.3/virtualenv.py
python virtualenv.py mypy
source mypy/bin/activate
pip install pudb
```

Source that `activate` file whenever you want to get into the environment. Run `deactivate` (an alias defined by `activate`) to get out. Make sure to use the python in the environment (ie `#!/usr/bin/env python`) rather than hard-coding a particular python instance.

Comment: printing the sys.argv[3] prints exactly GL